# la applicacion se detiene cuando llamo a PeripheralManager

Tags: java, android-studio, io

estoy siguiendo esta  [guia de android developers](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart#java)  para poder usar PeripheralManager para encontrar los periféricos disponibles en el dispositivo , en el activity_main.xml tengo un botón que llama a  la función  `verSerialPort`  pero al presionar el botón la aplicación se detiene.  GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.holajorge;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.things.pio.PeripheralManager;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public  void verSerialPort(View v){
        PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
        List<String> deviceList = manager.getUartDeviceList();
        if (deviceList.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"No UART port available on this device.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.i(TAG, "No UART port available on this device.");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"List of available devices: " ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.i(TAG, "List of available devices: " + deviceList);
        }

    }
}
```

Build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.holajorge"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.7-devpreview'
}
```

Comment: has agregado los permisos? que error se ve en el logcat?

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta , si agregue esta linea en el AndroidManifest.xml  "<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />"  la puse antes de la etiqueta <application>

Comment: Si deseas desarrollar en Android es muy importante el uso del LogCat, te sugiero revisar que mensaje de error se despliega en el LogCat, de esta forma será rapido encontrar una solución.